# How to move items in combo box using keyboard keys?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, key

Ex:
Combo box1:

Thanks Up and down arrow keys works when combo box has its focus. 
But how can i use characters to select items on combo box.
Ex: Apple,Banana,Orange are the items on combo box
and when i got focus on it and i press A key on keyboard Combo box item will display Apple.

Winforms..

Comment: Is this WinForms, Silverlight, WebForms, WPF?

Comment: If by "move" you mean show next or previous item as selected, then it is automatic you don't need to do anything for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, this is the default behavior when the ComboBox has focus.

If you're not clicking on the ComboBox, you're going to have to do something about it:

- Listen for the `MouseEnter` event and set focus on the ComboBox.
- Or, use Key Preview, listen for the <kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys, check the mouse position, and act accordingly.